# how to dynamically change the value of an xml node with php

Tags: php, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <SMS>
        <authentification>
            <username>xxxx</username>
            <password>xxxx</password>
        </authentification>
        <recipients>
            <number>8309042932</number>
        </recipients>
    </SMS>
```

my number node has a dynamically generated numbers for different people, i want to load all the numbers, but am getting only the last number.

Code used to create the xml string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
$xmlstring = 
"<SMS> 
     <authentification> 
        <username>xxxx</username> 
        <password>xxxx</password> 
     </authentification> 
     <recipients>"; 
foreach($gsmnumbers as $number) { 
   $number = explode(",", $number); 
   foreach($number as $num) { 
      $count = count($num); 
      for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
         $xmlHalf = "<gsm>$num</gsm>"; 
      }
   }
} 
$xmlSecondHalf = "</recipients> </SMS>";
```

Comment: Add the code to show how you are building this XML file? Otherwise we have no idea how to answer this question

Comment: please you guys should help out. i have a variable of array that is holding the number, then i used the foreach to iterate through the array to get the the numbers, and i did. but when i put it into the xml string, it only sees the last number.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
$xmlstring = 
    "<SMS>
    <authentification>
        <username>xxxx</username>
        <password>xxxx</password>
    </authentification>
    <recipients>";
  foreach($gsmnumbers as $number) {
      $number = explode(",", $number);
  foreach($number as $num) {
  $count = count($num);
          for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $xmlHalf = "<gsm>$num</gsm>";
      }
  }
 }
 $xmlSecondHalf = "</recipients>
</SMS>";

Comment: I have added that to the question, with an edit, which is what you should have done

Answer (score 0):

Try this, all sorts of mistakes in your code.

Basically if you use the `.=` syntax, you can concatenate to the end of an existing string where just using `=` will replace the string with the new value.

Also the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` need to be in the string to identify it as a valid XML string.

```
$xmlstring = '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<SMS> 
     <authentification> 
        <username>xxxx</username> 
        <password>xxxx</password> 
     </authentification> 
     <recipients>'; 

foreach($gsmnumbers as $number) { 
   $nums = explode(",", $number); 
   foreach($nums as $num) { 
       $xmlstring .= "<gsm>$num</gsm>"; 
   }
} 
$xmlstring .= "</recipients></SMS>";
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked. Am really a dutch bag. I really need to start thinking logically. Hey! thanks once more.

Comment: I am not sure my friends in the Netherlands would be pleased with that description! Hehe. Typo's Rule KO!

Comment: please i have a return xml string that i got from the server and am trying to get the value. how do i go about that?

Comment: What happened, you said that the code suggested worked, has the question changed? If it has you have to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write XML as string, use a XML library for that. A library normally prevents you from shooting into your own foot when it comes to creating XML. It also makes your code more readable. Example:

```
// process and transform input data

$gsmnumbers = ['1234,5678,9012'];
$gsms = [];
foreach ($gsmnumbers as $number) {
    $nums = explode(",", $number);
    foreach ($nums as $num) {
        $gsms[] = $num;
    }
}

// create XML

$request = new SimpleXMLElement('<SMS/>');

$authentication = $request->addChild('authentification');
$authentication->username = 'XXXX';
$authentication->password = 'XXXX';

$recipients = $request->addChild('recipients');    
foreach ($gsms as $gsm) {
    $recipients->addChild('gsm', $gsm);
}

echo $request->asXML();
```

Example output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SMS><authentification><username>XXXX</username><password>XXXX</password></authentification><recipients><gsm>1234</gsm><gsm>5678</gsm><gsm>9012</gsm></recipients></SMS>
```